# ts-node and custom loaders

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, es6-modules

Is it possible to use ts-node and a custom loader? In the docs I only see a way to enable [esm compatibility](https://typestrong.org/ts-node/docs/options/#esm).

```
ts-node --esm my-file.ts
```

I am trying to use a custom loader for testing an ESM module but I don't want to use node to compile each time since this is for a test suite. The way to use (multiple) loaders in node is like so

```
node --loader=esm --loader=testdouble my-file.js
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure: Just use `ts-node/esm` as the loader value. Using it in your command looks like this:

```sh
node --loader=ts-node/esm --loader=testdouble my-file.ts
```

This is [documented as an environment variable in `ts-node`'s README](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/tree/6ab696c619e1f2627a2a8fa5b62c87de20014cd9#other):

> Or, if you require native ESM support:
>
> ```
> NODE_OPTIONS="--loader ts-node/esm"
> ```
>
> This tells any node processes which receive this environment variable to install ts-node's hooks before executing other code.

Be sure to understand:

- the caveats of this loader: [GitHub — TypeStrong/ts-node#1007](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/1007)
- how the Loader API works in Node: [Node.js — API > ESM > Loaders](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#loaders)

---

Edit: Here's a reproducible example:

`./package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "so-73217517",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "type": "module",
  "devDependencies": {
    "testdouble": "^3.17.2",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^5.0.4"
  }
}
```

`./tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
  }
}
```

`./td_version.ts`:

```ts
// The "version" export seems to be missing from testdouble's type definitions:
declare module "testdouble" {
  export const version: string;
}

export { version } from "testdouble";
```

`./example.ts`:

```ts
import { version } from "./td_version.ts";

console.log("Testdouble version:", version);
```

In the terminal:

```txt
% node --version
v18.16.0

% node --loader=ts-node/esm --loader=testdouble example.ts
(node:60638) ExperimentalWarning: Custom ESM Loaders is an experimental feature and might change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:60638) Warning: Loader hook "getGlobalPreloadCode" has been renamed to "globalPreload"
(node:60638) DeprecationWarning: Obsolete loader hook(s) supplied and will be ignored: getFormat, getSource
Testdouble version: 3.17.2
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. He asked if he can use ts-node loader and another custom loader (example in question is testdouble)

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73217517/ts-node-and-custom-loaders/73217816?noredirect=1#comment134337748_73217816) @DanielGruszczyk The asker seemed confused about the value to use for `ts-node`'s loader — otherwise, their CLI command is correct. I've [updated](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/73217816/2) the answer to be more explicit, including a reproducible example. Did you find something else confusing?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73217517/ts-node-and-custom-loaders/73217816#comment134337748_73217816) @DanielGruszczyk It appears that the maintainers have echoed the information in this answer in response to your question in the GitHub repository: [testdouble/testdouble.js#514](https://github.com/testdouble/testdouble.js/issues/514)

Comment: Indeed, your updated answer seems to be correct

Comment: this is not working: i use my stub loader for css-modules and it crashes with